# Count by unique ID, group by another

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I've inherited some scripts that count the number of people in a team by department; the current scripts create a table for each individual department and the previous user would copy/paste the data into Excel. I've been tasked to pull this report into SSRS so I need one table for all the departments by team.

**Current Table**

```
+-------+-----------+---------+
| Dept  | DataMatch |  Team   |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|    01 | 4687Joe   | Dodgers |
|    01 | 3498Cindy | RedSox  |
|    01 | 1057Bob   | Yankees |
|    01 | 0497Lucy  | Dodgers |
|    02 | 7934Jean  | Yankees |
|    02 | 4584Tom   | Dodgers |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

**Desired Results**

```
+-------+---------+--------+---------+
| Dept  | Dodgers | RedSox | Yankees |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+
|    01 |       2 |      1 |       1 |
|    02 |       1 |      0 |       1 |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+
```

The DataMatch field is the unique identifier I will be counting. I started by wrapping each department in a CTE however this results in the Dept as the Column which would not work for my report, so I need to transpose my results and I haven't been able to figure that out. There are 60 departments and my query was getting very long.

**Current query**

```
SELECT Dept, DataMatch, Team INTO #temp_Team
FROM TeamDatabase
WHERE Status = 14
    AND Team <> 'Missing'   
;WITH A_cte (Team, Dept01) 
AS
    (
    SELECT Team
        , COUNT(DISTINCT datamatch) AS 'Dept01' 
    FROM #temp_Team
    WHERE Dept = '01'
    GROUP BY Team
    ), 
B_cte (Team, Dept02) AS 
    (
    SELECT Team
        , COUNT(DISTINCT datamatch) AS 'Dept02' 
    FROM #temp_Team
    WHERE Dept = '02'
    GROUP BY Team
    )
SELECT A_cte.Team
    , A_cte.Dept01
    , B_cte.Dept02
FROM A_cte
INNER JOIN B_cte
    ON A_cte.Team=B_cte.Team
```

**Which results in:**

```
+----------------------------+-------+-------+
|            Team            | Prg01 | Prg02 |
+----------------------------+-------+-------+
| RedSox                     |   144 |   141 |
| Yankees                    |    63 |   236 |
| Dodgers                    |   298 |   196 |
+----------------------------+-------+-------+
```

I feel that using a pivot on my already very long query would be excessive and impact performance, 60 departments with over 30,000 rows.

**What, mostly likely basic, step am I missing?**

***TL;DR - How do I count people by team and list by department?***

Comment: Why do you want to get this dataset formatted previously?, just use it as a source to your report and actually use the tools from SSRS to get the result you want (that's what a tablix is for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow what relevance your existing query has, but to get from your current table to your desired results is a pretty straightforward usage of `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
PIVOT(COUNT(DataMatch) FOR Team IN (Dodgers,RedSox,Yankees))pvt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0fac6/1/0)

And this of course could be done dynamically if the teams list isn't static.

Comment: This resulted in a line for each person with a "1" in the correct column.

Comment: @silviak Does the sample table in your question not match the actual table format?  The demo linked works out, but it might need tweaking if the table structure is different.

Comment: The sample table was simplified, I only listed the relevant fields to my question. My actual data contains personal identifiers so I stayed as close to as possible the actual format.   Over the weekend, I did work with it and succeeded! I added a temp table since some of my fields had names that needed to be updated (remove some punctuation). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the whole query with a dynamic pivot instead of adding a pivot to your CTEs.

You can add your Status/Team conditions to the SELECT inside the dynamic query at the bottom.  They would be `WHERE STATUS=14 AND TEAM !=''MISSING''` - note that is two single quotes to nest it within the string.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #data
CREATE TABLE #data (Dept VARCHAR(50), DataMatch NVARCHAR(50), Team VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #data (Dept, DataMatch, Team) 
VALUES ('01', '4687Joe','Dodgers'), 
       ('01', '3498Cindy','RedSox'),
       ('01', '1057Bob','Yankees'),
       ('01', '0497Lucy','Dodgers'),
       ('02', '7934Jean','Yankees'),
       ('02', '4584Tom','Dodgers')


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Team AS y FROM #data) AS Y
ORDER BY y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');        

SET @sql = 'SELECT Dept, '+@cols+'
            FROM (SELECT Dept, DataMatch, Team
                  FROM #data D) SUB
            PIVOT (COUNT([DataMatch]) FOR Team IN ('+@cols+')) AS P'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

In case you don't want to use a dynamic pivot, here is just a stand-alone query... again, add your conditions as you need.

```
SELECT Dept, Dodgers, RedSox, Yankees
FROM (SELECT Dept, DataMatch, Team
      FROM #data D) SUB
PIVOT (COUNT([DataMatch]) FOR Team IN ([Dodgers], [RedSox], [Yankees])) AS P
```